# How can I calculate the viscosity of a fluid at a given temperature with a logarithmic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the following computational expression assuming I've interpreted it correctly from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TLrd.png). It is part of a larger chart of fluid viscosity viewable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad1Jb.png).

Given this formula, I should in theory be able to calculate the viscosity of a fluid from that chart at a given temperature using the below expression.

$$log(n^t) = \frac{763.1}{273 + t}-2.559 + log(n^{25})$$
where:

- $n^t$ = kinematic viscosity (mm²/s) at $t$°C and
- $t$ = -25 to 250°C

I am struggling to determine the calculated viscosity of a 100 mm²/s fluid at a given temperature. But for example, -19°C which should be $\approx 270 $ mm²/s.

*mm²/s = cSt = centistoke*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $100 mm^2/s$ fluid, $\eta^{25}=10^2$.

\begin{align}\log_{10}(\eta^{-19})&=\frac{763.1}{273-19}-2.559 + \log_{10}(10^2) \\
&\approx0.44533070866+\log_{10}(10^2)\end{align}

$$\eta^{-19}\approx 10^2\cdot 10^{0.44533070866}\approx 279$$

Comment: So, basically I just need to do this? $10^{((763.1/(273+t))-2.559)}*v$ where $v$ = viscosity and $t$ = temperature?

Comment: seems to be so, where $v$ is the viscosity at temperatuare $25$.